# Increase event handling speed in Twisted?

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted

I have a python Twisted SSLServer that accepts SSL encoded messages over say 100 persistent connections from 100 different external clients. Each client is sending messages via its own SSLClient reactor. Each client is pushing approximately 20 small "messages" per second over its persistent socket connection to the server. The problem is that some of the clients are experiencing situations where one of the messages it sends does not get received and processed by the server until 5-10 minutes later.

The messages are sent from the clients in a staggered fashion (i.e. not all exactly on 0 seconds of every minute, but spread out randomly over that minute). Also, while the client sends these methods from inside a LoopingCall, it does indeed wrap the send message (sendLine) method inside callFromThread so that they are sent from the client's reactor thread.

My understanding of Twisted is that it takes each message that it receives and puts it in a queue, first come first served, and then just processes each message in that order. From our log files it does not look like any of our message handlers on the server are blocking or taking much time, but there seem to be a large number of them.

So my question is, is there any way to enable Twisted to process a larger number of events in a given amount of time? Anything like increasing a threadpool size? Any other ideas?

Our machine is fairly powerful (dual processor Xeon with 4 cores each and 32GB of RAM) so I'm surprised we are seeing this issue. I am guessing we are doing something not quite right with our Twisted server setup.

Comment: Are you certain that the delay lies in the message handlers' receipt of the messages?  For example, have you set the handlers to, say, write to a log whenever they get a new message?

Comment: Yes we have done that. We have added timing log messages to each event handler on our server, so it prints out start and end time of each handler. As I said, it doesn't look like any handler take a long time, just that there are lots of messages to handle.

Comment: I've done speed tests using LoopingCall,and the fastest performance I can get out of it is approximately 50-60Hz, and that's with a simple function that only adds to a counter.One more thing to check out is that the LoopingCall in Twisted is not monotonic, so if your clock has any jumps in time due to NTP/chrony then Twisted will delay or send early these packets. See: https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/2424  The author of Twisted (Glyph) essentially says at the end of this thread that Twisted will not use a monotonic clock due to the difficulties of implementation. Look into asyncioreactor